# What does the apostrophe in the expression ‘I’ faith’ mean?

Tags: expressions, british-english, archaicisms

In older translations of Latin texts (and I would presume Greek as well), the phrase *I’ faith* is quite common. Examples from [Plautus’ *Menaechmus* 2.2 and 2.3](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0101%3Aact%3D2%3Ascene%3D2):

> CYLINDRUS
> I’ve catered well, and to my mind. I’ll set a good breakfast before the breakfasters. But see, I perceive Menaechmus. Woe to my back; the guests are now already walking before the door, before I’ve returned with the provisions. I’ll go and accost him. Save you, Menaechmus.
> MENAECHMUS SOSICLES
> The Gods bless you, whoever you are. …
> CYLINDRUS
> … who I am?
> MESSENIO
> **I’ faith**, not I, indeed.
>
> ⋮
>
> MESSENIO
> **I’ faith**, ’tis far from surprising: courtesans have this custom; they send servant-boys and servant-girls down to the harbour; if any foreign ship comes into port, they enquire of what country it is, and what its name is; after that, at once they set themselves to work, and fasten themselves upon him; if they inveigle him, they send him home a ruined man. Now in this harbour there stands a piratical craft, against which I really think that we must be on our guard.

From the Latin, it is clear that it is an exclamation of sorts. (The first case: ‘Men.: Nōn hercle vērō.’ And the second case: ‘Mess.¹ Minimē hercle mīrum.’) The problem is not with the Latin, but with the English expression itself. Searching my usual dictionaries, I find no entries for this sort of language, which by now has become archaic. My question thus is:

- What is the apostrophe indicating? I am assuming it is a missing verb.
- What does the expression *I’ faith* really mean?

---

¹ Apparently there is an error in either the English or Latin text here. The Latin has is as Menaechmus speaking; the English as Messeniō.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe indicates a missing *letter*. "In faith" was a mild expletive at the time these translations were made. https://www.yourdictionary.com/i-faith

It has been used to represent the Latin exclamation "Hercle!" (By Hercules!)

Comment: Because all the instances I came upon it had _i_ at the beginning of the sentence, I thought it was the pronoun, so something like _I’ll_, _I’ve_, _I’m_; for that reason, I alway read it as /ɑɪ̯ feɪ̯θ/. Now, in 5.1, I actually came upon it mid-sentence (‘THE WIFE OF MENAECHMUS of Epidamnus.
If you laugh at me, still, i' troth, you can't do so at him; my father, I mean, who's coming here. Why don't you look back? Do you know that person?’), and so your answer makes perfect sense.